# Compiling coffeescript on npm install

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, npm

I'm building an app consisting of [private npm repos](http://debuggable.com/posts/private-npm-modules:4e68cc7d-1ac4-42d9-995a-343dcbdd56cb) built in CoffeeScript. To keep deployment language-agnostic, and allow each app to specify its version of CoffeeScript, I'm including CoffeeScript as a dependency in each library, and building into JavaScript upon npm installation.

npm installation works fine for standalone repos, but fails when I try to install a repo that depends on another repo being built.

So if I have `repo-a`, whose `package.json` includes this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "coffee-script": "~1.2.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "install": "./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake install"
}
```

and `repo-b`, whose `package.json` includes this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "coffee-script": "~1.2.0",
  "repo-a": "git+ssh://git@mydomain.com:myrepo.git"
},
"scripts": {
  "install": "./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake install"
}
```

where both have a `Cakefile` that looks like this, with an `install` task called on an npm `install` hook:

```
{print} = require "util"
{spawn} = require "child_process"

coffee = "./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee"

echo = (child) ->
  child.stdout.on "data", (data) -> print data.toString()
  child.stderr.on "data", (data) -> print data.toString()
  child

install = (cb) ->
  console.log "Building..."
  echo child = spawn coffee, ["-c", "-o", "lib", "src"]
  child.on "exit", (status) -> cb?() if status is 0

task "install", "Install, build, and test repo", install
```

`npm install` works for for `repo-a`, but fails for `repo-b` with this message:

```
sh: ./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake: No such file or directory
```

at which point an unfinished `___coffee-script.npm` directory exists in `node_modules`.

Of course it would be much easier to use a [app.js wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596230/use-coffee-instead-of-node-command-in-production), but I need to deploy JavaScript, not CoffeeScript. Can anyone tell me how I could get this to work?

Comment: for what it's worth, this approach works when I rely on a global `cake` binary, and only fails because i'm specifying the locally installed `cake`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things.

1. If you're running cake from an npm command, you can just specify `cake install` or `cake build` as the scripts.install field.  This will run *after* coffee-script has been installed locally, and its bin linked appropriately (with a shim on windows), and will run with a PATH environ such that the locally installed `cake` is used rather than anything else in the system path.
2. If you're *not* running this from an npm command, but you are nonetheless expecting that coffee-script has already been installed locally via npm (which it looks like), then you should probably be hitting `./node_modules/.bin/cake` or `./node_modules/.bin/coffee` rather than diving into the package internals.

If you are not installing coffee-script with npm, but instead using some git submodules or something, then you're on your own :)

Comment: many thanks, isaac. i didn't realize npm's scope extended to `bin`, that's awesome news. the more i learn about "npm the tool" (as opposed to "npm the repo of repos") the more i love it. it's a great piece of software.

Comment: Appending `node_modules/.bin/` to `PATH` (1.) is really neat since we can just use node_module's binaries as regular ones. Thanks for sharing this awesome trick!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to locally build the JS and store the compiled packages as `tar.gz` files on S3. For local development you can `npm link` and in production you point to the archive urls. If you don't want to version your dependencies you could just have the same url updated over and over.

Keep in mind this npm bug so: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1727 (you'll basically have to wipe your node_modules folder everytime you update the deps on an app that uses git/http urls as version numbers).

--fg

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the pointers, Felix. I think I'll end up going with [@jashkenas's solution](http://twitter.com/jashkenas/status/149516518802198528) for now, and compiling without commands from the provided module.