# What is the difference between running my app with coffee vs compile it and the run it as javascript?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Currently, I'm running my app like this `coffee app.coffee` but I wonder if it would be a better choice to compile it to javascript and then run it like this `node app.js`.

Thanks

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596230/use-coffee-instead-of-node-command-in-production?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your app through the `coffee` command is fine, as your code is initially converted to JavaScript before being passed to Node.  It's important to note that this happens up-front, and none of this parsing happens during runtime.